# Descriptor size of ORB

Tags: feature-detection, orb

I am currently working on ORB algorithm for feature extraction. By default the size of the descriptor is taken as 32 bytes as mentioned in the paper. But i need to check the performance of the descriptor with the reduced descriptor size say 16 bytes. How can I do this?

Comment: Currently do you implement the algorithm yourself or use an open source implementation like OpenCV?

Comment: currently i use open source from OPENCV

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has a fixed implementation of the orb descriptor. The binary test pattern is pre-generated (you can view the source at /modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp). I would recommend you to re-implement orb with a new test pattern. How the test pattern is trained, please refer to the paper [brief](http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/calonder_eccv10.pdf) and [orb](http://www.vision.cs.chubu.ac.jp/CV-R/pdf/Rublee_iccv2011.pdf).

Comment: Hey @Yu LU, How difficult is it to re-implement ORB with a new test pattern?

Comment: Could you please update the links? They are broken. Thank you!